# Write to and then read from file using PHP

Tags: php, file-get-contents, fwrite, fread

I'm trying to get the contents of a specific website, write the content to a .txt file and output unformatted result in my browser. I'm able to actually write the website content to my text file, but it won't echo out in my browser. I tried using "w+" and "r+" in my original handle but that didn't do the trick. What am I doing wrong here?

```
$file = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com');
$handle = fopen("text.txt", "w");
fwrite($handle, $file);
fclose($handle);

$myfile = "text.txt";
$handle = fopen($myfile, "r");
$read = htmlentities(fread($handle, filesize($myfile)));
echo $read;
```

Comment: You're code runs fine on my machine.

Comment: Can't see anything wrong with the code. Is test.txt correctly populated after the first block of code? If not, probably a permissions issue.

Comment: Is there a good reason for not simply doing `echo htmlentities(file_get_contents('http://www.example.com'));` ?

Comment: The reason is simply that I'm trying to learn the technique, so I do it the (slightly) hard(er) way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial statement of $file contains all of the formatted code from the file you just wrote so you can use that.

```
 echo htmlentities($file);
```

However, several people have asked this already.. perhaps the OP wants to verify that the file was written correctly?

Your code for opening looks fine, have you ruled out a permissions issue? check this by using is_readable($myFile) prior to opening it. You can also do an is_writable on the folder that your writing to to ensure that your actually writing the file.

Comment: The file is written correctly, and I stumbled upon something interesting just now. Example.com actually works, but that wasn't the URL I tried to fetch in my real code. Seems the code works well with some sites, but not with others. For example, google.com does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Some sites can block requests such as file_get_contents. Google.com will because it will very quickly classify you as a spammer - I have ran into that way way too often. You can get around this blocking by identifying as a browser. Lookup curl which will allow you to do that. As you said above your main aim is to learn and this will facilitate that end goal brilliantly.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to open the files multiple times .. just try

```
$file = "log.txt";
$url = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com' ;

$handle = fopen("log.txt", "w+");
fwrite($handle, file_get_contents($url));
rewind($handle);

$read = htmlentities(fread($handle, filesize($file)));
echo $read;
```

Comment: Thanks! That simplifies things.

Answer (score 0):

You can var_dump() the $handle and see if it can be opened. If yes, var_dump($read)..

And to read files you can also use file_get_contents().